# Scaling load profiles for simulation

Tags: simulation, matlab, load

I am trying to simulate the behaviour of my power converter when it is subjected to different load conditions (in this case a refrigerator load).

I have the load profile of a refrigerator load that operates off a 9.5kW motor, but I am more interested in motors that operate at 12.5kW. I however, do not have load profiles for a 12.5kW motor.

In the absence of a 12.5kW load profile, I am considering scaling up the values from the 9.5kW load profile by a factor of 1.3 (12.5kW/9.5kW). I am more interested in how the shape of the profile affects the operation of my device. Am I missing something by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how accurate you want your simulation to be. For some rough cut numbers doing what you describe and scaling up the 9.5 KW motor works. Ideally you would find the load chart for the exact motor you want to use, you can contact manufacturers and they should be able to give you a load chart